# How to use multi-threaded .NET object in OpenEdge

Tags: .net, multithreading, openedge, progress-4gl

I am using the .NET SmtpClient class to send an email from an AppServer procedure. I have implemented some simple code to test, based on the syntax found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

All of the OpenEdge syntax is correct (using the class browser, it is simple to translate the code), but the problem line is here:

```
mailClient:send(mailMessage).
```

When running the code the following error is shown:

You are trying to use a multi-threaded .NET object in a way that is not supported. The ABL cannot be called on a thread other than the main thread. (15740)
The ABL is single threaded. You will see this error if you use a .NET object that employs multiple threads and attempts to call back to the ABL on a thread other than the main processing thread.

My question is how do you use a multi-threaded .NET object in ABL since it is single threaded.

Initially documentation suggested using the `WAIT-FOR` statement, however this did not change the result.

Comment: I'm a little confused, looking at the [MSDN site of the SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h(v=vs.110).aspx)  it looks like the `send` method is not async, there is a special `SmtpClient.SendAsync` method for that, also many other methods with a prefix `Async`!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple answer. If you do not need the response of the method, you can create a wrapper method in C#. If you need the response from the send method, you will be out of luck on the AppServer - as this would require the thread synchronization only possible with WinForm controls.

Comment: Ah I See. I would need the response to check that the email was sent and that there were no errors thrown. So this check would also need to be wrapped up in C#?